# Virtual Machines in Windows Server 2012 Core Hyper-V going Off-Critical

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I have a server running Windows Server 2012 Core Hyper-V. This server currently hosts two virtual machines (one Windows Server 2008 and one Windows Web Server 2008). Occasionally, without any warning, I am unable to access any of the VM’s.
By using Hyper-V Manager to connect to the host, I can see that they got an `Off-Critical` state.

If I try to start them, I get a `"An attempt to read or update virtual machine configuration failed."` error message. I'm only able to start the VM’s by restarting the host itself.

By looking at the **logs on both of the VM’s**, I don’t see anything that might help me figure out what is going on:

- The last event logged, before going down, is an Info about the uptime (`“The system uptime is 70378 seconds.”`),
- ...followed by another one stating that the OS has started, an Error saying that the previous shutdown was unexpected and a Critical saying `“The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly.”`.

Looking at the **host's logs** doesn't help much either. I don't see any error messages around the time the VM's got shut down suddenly:

- Just two Info's about Windows Update service starting and stopping (unrelated as they happen 2-3 hours before the VMs' crashes)
- ...followed by a (more suspicious) Warning `"Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort1, was issued."` (@ some seconds after the VMs crashed) and a whole bunch of `"The IO operation at logical block address 0x... for Disk 1 was retried."` ones. Perhaps this could be related?

Any ideas on what might be causing my VM's to crash? Suggestions on actions to be taken? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time I have seen this happening is with underlying storage issues either dodgy SSD, or running out of space.  if that's not it please give us somne more info

Comment: This should probably be a comment  until conclusive :)

Comment: This might be the cause. I'm testing it and will mark the answer as accepted as soon as I'm sure.

Comment: Looks like there are indeed issues one of the hard drives (problem doesn't occur if I unplug it). Gotta replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Check your disk and storage sub-system health. Also make sure that antivirus is configured as required for Hyper-V: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2179.hyper-v-anti-virus-exclusions-for-hyper-v-hosts.aspx